# Logging HAProxy connection limiting

Tags: haproxy, rate-limiting

I have some simple connection and connection rate limiting in HAProxy:

```
    # Store IPs to limit connection rate
    stick-table type ip size 200k expire 5m store gpc0,conn_cur,conn_rate(10s)
    tcp-request connection track-sc0 src

    # Abusers are immediately rejected
    tcp-request connection reject if { sc0_get_gpc0 gt 0 }

    # Test connection count and rate
    acl connabuse sc0_conn_cur gt 20
    acl connkill  sc0_inc_gpc0 gt 0
    tcp-request connection reject if connabuse connkill

    acl rateabuse sc0_conn_rate gt 30
    acl ratekill  sc0_inc_gpc0 gt 0
    tcp-request connection reject if rateabuse ratekill
```

Unfortunately, this has been causing some problems.  I'd like to temporarily stop blocking people, but log the time and IP when those limits are hit, so I can play around with the rules and see what works and what doesn't.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of blocking abusers you could add response headers indicating client IP address that broke the rules. Something like this:

```
http-request add-header X-Haproxy-Abuse %ci if connabuse
http-request add-header X-Haproxy-Kill %ci if connkill
```

where %ci represents Client IP address, you can log any other  param mentioned here: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#8.2.4

Than you capture that headers and put them in logs as described in docs: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#capture%20response

```
capture response header X-Haproxy-Abuse 15
capture response header X-Haproxy-Kill len 15
```

Comment: Great!  That's a very clever way to achieve this.  I'm marking this as the accepted answer, even though I won't actually get to try this out for a while.